# Execute PHP script on remote server using CLI without SSH

Tags: php, ssh, command-line-interface

I am building a web-API for one of my tools and attempting to avoid browser prefetching and other errors associated with HTTP. In order to circumvent this I am forcing CLI interaction using the following function:

```
function isCLI()
{
    return php_sapi_name() == 'cli';
}
```

However, I have run into the issue of having to use [ssh2_exec](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ssh2-exec.php) to execute the script from a remote machine. Using this, however, forces me to give out the login information to my server to anyone wanting to interact with my API.

Is there any way around having to distribute the login information to my server in order for people to interact with my API using CLI? I haven't been able to find anything thus far.

Comment: Without trying to tackle whether this could be possible by HTTP, have you considered public key authentication?

Comment: This sounds like a ridiculously scary and complicated method of dealing with browser prefetching... There's a reason no one's APIs run this way.

Comment: @ceejayoz Any recommendations on dealing with prefetching?

Comment: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/33415/is-it-possible-to-stop-chrome-and-other-browsers-from-pre-fetching-rendering-my

Comment: @asdf My recommendation is don't worry about it. Browsers will only prefetch GET requests. If your GET requests are destructive, your API needs reworking.

Comment: @ceejayoz That is precisely the issue. I had random additions to my SQL DB caused by prefetching.

Comment: @asdf Either you're adding stuff via GET (dangerous and wrong) or you've got a bug somewhere. The browser that have implemented prefetch will prefetch GET requests, but not POST/DELETE/PATCH/etc. requests.

Comment: @ceejayoz The page is an API for people to add information to a DB for analysis throughout my company. It is going to be called from other scripts and thus GET requests are desirable instead of a UI interaction. Is there any way to enforce I have a real connection instead of a prefetch while still using HTTP and GET?

Comment: @asdf This argumentation does not make sense (to me). Eg via `curl` it is no problem to send POST/PUT/... requests from inside a PHP script

Comment: @kingkero I had no idea. Thank you very much that makes my life a lot easier :)

Comment: "It is going to be called from other scripts and thus GET requests are desirable instead of a UI interaction." GET requests are **not** desirable. Have the API clients make POST requests (cURL, Guzzle, etc.). No UI interaction required. If your API clients are browsers, you can at least limit destructive actions to JSONP requests.

Comment: @asdf You're welcome. I recently started using [Guzzle](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle) myself, maybe that makes it easier for you instead of digging into curl docu

Comment: What prefetching are you trying to stop? According to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Link_prefetching_FAQ, only `<link>` elements should be prefetched. It shouldn't prefetch `<a>` elements. There are many sites that use `<a>` links for things like deleting items from the DB, it would be crazy if the browser prefetched them.